# FlowJS inline curried function types with Union

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

How to write inline curried function types in Flow with Union?

The following example works ok:

```
type Foo = () => () => string;

function func(foo: Foo): string {
    return foo()();
}
```

Here is the problem with Union:

```
type Foo = () => string | () => () => string;

function func(foo: Foo): string {
    const f = foo();
    if (typeof f === 'function') {
      return f(); // Cannot return `f()` because function type [1] is incompatible with string [2].
    }
    return f;
}
```

But, it can be fixed by doing:

```
type TF = () => string;
type Foo = TF | () => TF;

function func(foo: Foo): string {
    const f = foo();
    if (typeof f === 'function') {
      return f();
    }
    return f;
}
```

So how can I write inline curried function types with Union?

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiSgC4E8AOBTUAVAMVAF5QAKASlID5QBnNAJwEsA7AcwG4UxNdQhWLFIFiAHwrUSdIj0T88QkWSq0Gzdh1CS1MqesatO8yAFc2AYzQtYbUOavlIwgFyDhld0a2gA3ogAkJZ2jA6iLrBUPIEskBSKsPHxJKmgAOSO1rZs6dQBoIVFTDhoZkz2kNGIRaAAvjWggSVlFQ48DSgAVArYSsKienRDGsbcyFk2dg4Wls5uHrBeo74FTS3llcJU1Q1dwEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
type Foo = () => string | () => () => string;
```

Currently this is saying that `Foo` is a function type with a return type of:

```
string | () => () => string
```

Which is not what you want. If you add some parens, flow will make proper sense of this:

```
type Foo = (() => string) | () => () => string;
```

([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKVBKZA+KBnYAJwEsA7AcywB80sldMd8izyBuAKA4DMBXUgMbBicUlD6DU3BAC5YCDHIIkKUAN4coWqANEFxycQkydtUYtzShIcS5aQOoAcglCRpJ1g1mthCMF5CMW4TKAB6MKgAYQBDUlI4YCg-AKCoAAMQjHSoACMIARjePGhXYVEoa2gAbQBGAF1zPHNBOABbMBjhXIAbaAB3YmAAC2YVcihqgCZ6gDpNbQBfBd9-QODORaA))